# Extending Python list functionalities

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extending the functionalities of a Python list and I would like to include a method to normalize a vector to the `[0, 1]` range, by using element-wise operations. I came out with this solution, but find that using two classes does not seem clean. The main motivation for using two classes is that the output of `data - min(data)` from `normalize()` returns a Python list (due to how `__sub__()` was implemented), and that native list does not seem to have `__truediv__()` implemented.

How can I achieve the `normalize()` method and avoid the creation of the intermediate `_BaseList` class? The project I am working on has very constrained memory and I cannot use Numpy.

```
class _BaseList(list):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(data)

    def __sub__(self, value):
        if type(value) in (int, float):
            return [elem - value for elem in self]
        elif type(value) is list and len(value) == len(self):
            return [a - b for a, b in zip(value, self)]

    def __truediv__(self, value):
        if type(value) in (int, float):
            return [elem / value for elem in self]
        elif type(value) is list and len(value) == len(self):
            return [a / b for a, b in zip(value, self)]


class Array(_BaseList):

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super().__init__(data)

    def normalize(self):
        print(type(self))
        return _BaseList((self - min(self))) / float(max(self) - min(self))
```

Comment: Why do you need to extend list? Are there existing methods that you'll make extensive use of?

Comment: Also, is it only `normalize` that you need to add or do you plan on adding more methods?

Comment: Are you re implementing `numpy`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You say you need the extra class, *"due to how `__sub__()` was implemented"*; because it returns a vanilla `list`, with a list comprehension. However, note:

1. If you replace e.g.

   ```
   return [elem - value for elem in self]
   ```

   with:

   ```
   return _BaseList(elem - value for elem in self)
   ```

   `__sub__` will return a `_BaseList` instead; and
2. If you put those four methods in one class calling `normalize` would still work anyway, because you *do* convert to `_BaseList` after the subtraction.

---

In fact, *three* methods, because the `__init__` is redundant - if all your subclass method does is call the superclass version, you can just let Python handle that for you.

---

[The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states that

> Errors should never pass silently.

However, in both `__truediv__` and `__sub__`, if `value` is not one of the three specified types (or it's a list of the wrong length), they quietly return `None`. Instead, you should `raise TypeError` if the user passes a value that can't be handled.

---

Speaking of specified types, don't write things like:

```
if type(value) in (int, float)
```

If you need to check types, use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) - this supports inheritance better:

```
if isinstance(value, (int, float)):
```

This is particularly important when you're using inheritance yourself - what happens if you try to subtract a `_BaseList` from another `_BaseList`? Python supplies [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) that can help make this usage more generic.

Also note that there is another [numeric type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex): `complex` - as [Mathias Ettinger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger) pointed out in the comments you can use [`Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) when you want to cover all three cases.

---

There's a lot of duplication between the `__sub__` and `__truediv__` implementations; you could factor this out by extracting to a method that also takes the operator to apply, then use the operators defined in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

---

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from operators import sub, trudiv


class Array(list):

    def normalize(self):
        min_ = min(self)  # calculate this once
        return (self - min_) / (max(self) - min_)

    def __sub__(self, other):
       return self._process(other, sub)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
       return self._process(other, truediv)

    def _process(self, other, op):
        if isinstance(other, Sequence):
            if len(other) == len(self):
                return Array(op(a, b) for a, b in zip(self, other))
            raise ValueError('cannot operate on a sequence of unequal length')
        return Array(op(a, other) for a in self)
```

In use:

```
>>> a = Array((7, 8, 9))
>>> a
[7, 8, 9]
>>> a - 2
[5, 6, 7]
>>> a - [1, 2, 3]
[6, 6, 6]
>>> a.normalize()
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
>>> a - 'abc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __sub__
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in _process
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <genexpr>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
>>> a - [1, 2, 3, 4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __sub__
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in _process
ValueError: cannot operate on a sequence of unequal length
```

It might also be worth implementing `__repr__`, so you can tell more easily when you have a vanilla `list` and when you have an `Array`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the suggestions! Just adapted them for this specific constrained context, and they work great.